# Plugin doesn't interacting with div

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, append

I use a plugin called grid rotator it works with div objects that are already have been declared in the html page. But the issue is if I append a div with jquery into my html and when I initialize the plugin again to the div. The plugin stopts working for the div. How can I fix this problem so that the plugin works even after I append divs with jquery later when the page is loaded? Anyone?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {

        var BASE_PATH = 'js/brands/';
        var array_brands = <?php echo json_encode($array_brands); ?>;
        var directory = null;
        $.each(array_brands, function(key, value) {
            arr = array_brands[key];
            if($('.' + arr['directories'])) {
                $.each($(this), function (key, value) {
                    var res = $(this)[key]['filenames'].split(',');
                    directory = $(this)[key]['directories'];
                    console.log($(this)[key]['filenames']);
                    $.each(res, function(key, value) {
                        $('<li><a href="#"><img src="' + BASE_PATH + directory + '/' + res[key] + '"/></a></li>').clone().appendTo($('#' + 'ri-grid-' + directory + ' ul');
                     });
                });
            }
$.each($('#' + 'ri-grid-' + directory + ' ul li'), function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
console.log($('#ri-grid-' + directory).gridrotator());
            $('#ri-grid-' + directory).gridrotator( {
                  rows    : 3,
                  columns   : 15,
                  animType  : 'fadeInOut',
                  animSpeed : 1000,
                  interval  : 600,
                  step    : 1,
                  w320    : {
                    rows  : 3,
                    columns : 4
                  },
                  w240    : {
                    rows  : 3,
                    columns : 4
                  }
                } );



        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The plugin is 'responsive image grid rotator'. I think it is because of this, the. Items are getting appended with jQuery, so they are not static in the HTML page itself, therefore the plugin has problems with it. I initialize the plugin to the div after the list items are created.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/
Correct me if I am wrong. The issue sounds to me like the div is being added to your document after grid rotator is initialized. If this is your plugin you want to put the initialization function after the div being added in jquery.

Comment: Yes, it is. But the div exists I am only adding the list items with images. Then I initialize the plugin.

Comment: Anyway, I fixed it. The issue here was that my array with filenames had a empty element. Therefore, the plugin crashed, bad coded it is. So, to fix it I simply made a check to ensure there are no empty elements (values) passed to my list. So, that the plugin can read the list without crashing, because it can't find an empty file in the given directory. Hope, this will clear things up. And my bad, I am still learning. Peace, and thanks in advance especially for the quick replies.